# Trouble with sorting a numerical array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
```

Above is my code. I am using the Khanacademy.com interface to make a program where the computer is give an array of numbers and it sorts them into ascending order. However, an error keeps coming up even though I copied this off a website and this method of sorting in JavaScript has been repeatedly stated across many websites.

The error that continues to appear states, "Did you forget to add a comma between two parameters?" Whenever I ask it to show me where, it always places my cursor here:

```
points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});
                                 ^
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code? Or if you have a better way of sorting numbers, I am fine with that, too.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the site. That code is just fine (if you want to sort in descending order). There is no missing comma after a parameter, etc.

Comment: They **may** be expecting you to use an arrow function (`points.sort((a, b) => b - a)`), but if so, they really should detect that you used a traditional function and say something clearer.

Comment: It looks good to me... (but since you are asking for it, it could be simplified using an array function to `points.sort((a, b) => b - a)`)

Comment: You all might be right. When I try what Cherry DT and T. J. Crowder told me, a different error popped up that said, "'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 which is not supported by this environment." Thank you, anyway!

Comment: Khanacademy.com is using an environment that doesn't support ES2015? In 2022? Really? That's....way surprising.

Comment: I think I'm just going to see if I can do it using iteration. Thank you everyone!